# GitLab: Create branch from only certain branches

Tags: git, branch, gitlab

Is there a way to set up a group or project so that developers can create branches only from certain branches? For example, I only want developers to create branches based off of `master`, but not from `unstablestuff`.

I would like to restrict creation of branches to be based off of a list of certain existing branches (or the opposite). You *can* only create `newbranch` from `stable1`, `stable2`, and `master`, but you *cannot* create from `unstablestuff1`, `unstablestuff2`, and `unstablestuff3`.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you need to protect unstable branches, but AFAIK you can not prevent branching off of a published branch in Git.

In GitLab you can make any branch a `protected branch` which will restrict push to users with `Master` permissions, prevents anyone from force pushing to the branch and prevents anyone from deleting the branch (see https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/). This will not prevent others from creating new branches from `unstablestuff1` but can prevent them from messing up the unstable branch.

An altertive would be to have stable branches in one (public) repo and unstable branches in another repo with restricted access (a clone of the stable repo). When a branch in the  unstable repo becomes 'stable' push it to the stable repo (or make a pull request) to publish the new stable branch.

Again, I don't see the use case here so I may be a bit off here.